# How to display image icons on nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am using NetworkX module to present the network of an infrastructure systems. In this systems, nodes and edges consist of different types of entities and I would like to use some icons representing their types instead of circle, star or square.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a', 'b')
nx.draw(G, labels={'a':'img1', 'b':'img2'}, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Obviously, my script creates a graph with labels of 'img1' and 'img2'. I am looking for a way to display two icons instead of the filled circles and labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a plot using networkx and get the handle to the figure. Then use matplotlib to plot ontop of it.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
from numpy import sqrt
import glob

path = 'some/folder/with/png/files'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "*.png")]
img = []
for f in files:
    img.append(mpimg.imread(f))
N = len(files)

# generate graph
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(N,4,0.2)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G,k=3/sqrt(N))

# draw with images on nodes
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos,width=3,edge_color="r",alpha=0.6)
ax=plt.gca()
fig=plt.gcf()
trans = ax.transData.transform
trans2 = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform
imsize = 0.1 # this is the image size
for n in G.nodes():
    (x,y) = pos[n]
    xx,yy = trans((x,y)) # figure coordinates
    xa,ya = trans2((xx,yy)) # axes coordinates
    a = plt.axes([xa-imsize/2.0,ya-imsize/2.0, imsize, imsize ])
    a.imshow(img[n])
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    a.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Found at https://gist.github.com/munthe/7de513dc886917860f7b960a51c95e10

[Here](https://gist.github.com/shobhit/3236373) is an example that seems to plot on the edges instead of the nodes.